# Can Jest reveal untested functions?

Tags: jestjs

Right now what setting 100% code coverage does is reveal if a function is not invoked at all. Ideally, what I'd like it to do is uncover function calls that are being made from production code(non-tests), but not invoked a single time from a it() test. It's hard to always remember to write all the unit tests up-front and this would be an excellent way to do exactly that.

Comment: How would this be helpful? You'd get a coverage report that told you that all of the implementation detail internal functions you extracted weren't covered by the tests, when in fact they _are_. Whether a function is directly or indirectly invoked by a test isn't very interesting - if they're _collaborators_ they should be replaced by test doubles.

Comment: The scenario is I code a function, then call that function from some other function in production code. I failed to write a unit test. How do I uncover that other than hitting integration testing and a bug happens?

Comment: If that function's not part of the public API, you _shouldn't_ unit test it, just like a private method. If you're getting full coverage all of its behaviour is apparently being tested via the indirect calls anyway. It's hard to say in the abstract.

Comment: To me an internal module has function(s) that are a 'internal API' that need testing just as valid as the actual public API method/controller function. I don't see how you ensure quality otherwise.

Comment: Yes, they do need testing. You _are testing them_, via the public API (apparently to full coverage, so quite thoroughly). It's unclear why you think calling them directly from the tests would improve quality, or find any bug that was actually reachable in real life (i.e. via the public API), but doing so would certainly make it harder to refactor (because then you have to decide at every step whether the tests that now fail were for implementation or behaviour) and thereby _reduce_ quality over time.

Comment: Istanbul does the code coverage.  You could configure it to run against the Javascript. However, I am not sure how this would work in Production, as everything tends to be configured to run from a testing suite. You could configured it to run the against Javascript files, but not sure how you would trigger all of this.  Maybe you need to consider another tool to re-run front end interface options (Storybook, etc.) and try to capture code coverage from there?

Comment: @StevenScott when the OP refers to "production code" I think they mean _implementation_, as opposed to test code, rather than an environment. But yes, Jest's coverage reporter uses Istanbul.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes that's what I mean implementation vs test code. I wonder if there is a canonical naming for that.